# Change default web browser to lynx from terminal

Tags: linux-mint, browser, defaults, file-opening, lynx

I'm on Linux Mint Olivia. I just installed Lynx.

How do I set Lynx as my browser, so when I open links from the terminal, they open in that terminal with Lynx?

Comment: not sure what you mean 'when I open links from the terminal'? In a terminal window you can open a webpage with lynx by typing e.g. `lynx http://www.mypage.com`.

Comment: `xdg-settings set default-web-browser lynx`

Comment: `sudo update-alternatives --set x-www-browser "$(which linx)"`

Comment: @Costas you've to provide `.desktop` application to `xdg-settings`

Comment: @gogoud It might be something like [this](http://imgur.com/0JpSv0H)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First make `.desktop` application for `lynx`:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Name=Lynx
Exec=gnome-terminal -e 'lynx %u'
```

And save it to application directory e.g `/usr/share/applications/` naming like `lynx.desktop` and give it execution permission (`chmod +x /usr/share/applications/lynx.desktop`).

Then set it as default web browser by using:

```
xdg-settings set default-web-browser lynx.desktop
```

Now try to `Open link` and it will be open with `lynx` in the terminal.

Note: `lynx` is command-line web-browser and hence it needs terminal so-that I've used `gnome-terminal` in my example `Exec` command. Your terminal application may be different. This works for me with my current system.

Comment: Linux Mint Olivia is derived from Debian; using `x-terminal-emulator` is the way to go, rather than hard-code specific terminal names.

Comment: if you add `--tab` after `gnome-terminal` it gets added to existing terminal windows

Answer (score 0):

Since I'm not using GNOME, I used the following for the `.desktop` file:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Name=Lynx
Exec=lynx %u
Terminal=true
Categories=Network;
Icon=/usr/share/applications/lynx.jpg
```

Changes include:

- Use the default terminal
- Added to category (try looking under "Internet")
- Added icon (included here)[image: lynx icon]